# How to verify the presence of a TPM (trusted platform module) in my laptop

Tags: windows-8, tpm

I have a Windows 8 laptop I will soon be upgrading to Windows 8.1. The standard Version of 8.1 allows for disk encryption if your PC has a TPM chip.

How do I detect this chip in my Windows 8 PC?

Answer (score 6):

The TPM may not show up in Device Manager if it's been disabled by the firmware.

Enter the firmware (colloquially BIOS) before booting Windows (typically F2, F10 at the manufacturer logo screen before Windows boots) and look for any TPM options.

Comment: The delete key is also a common option for getting in to the firmware setup screen.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the device manager. If a TPM is present, it will be listed under *System Devices*.

Answer (score 1):

Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, and then click Run.

Type tpm.msc in the Open box, and then press ENTER.

Comment: What will happen differently on machines with the chip from those without? Does this work even if it has been disabled in firmware?